# Dokka, Kotlin: How to get a DProperty's type? Or, in general, `DType` from `Bound`?

Tags: kotlin, parsing, documentation-generation, kotlin-dokka

In Dokka, which is Kotlin's documentation library / toolkit,

I want to get a type of a `DProperty`.

`DProprety.type` gives `Bound`.

What I need is rather some kind of type, like, `DType`.

How can I achieve that?

Dokka doesn't have much documentation, and this use case is not in the tests, as far as I can find.

Maybe I misunderstand some concept, and the relation between these two is way looser?